# Using an 'input' selection from launch.json to be used in a preLaunchTask in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

In a project there are a number of helper utilities.  In the launch and tasks json files they are configured to allow the user to select the particular utility to build or debug.  What I would like to do is have the selection from launch to be passed to the tasks and the task use that selection.  The launch.json configuration file looks like:

```
launch.json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug: <Utility App>",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/${input:utility}/${input:utility}",
            "args": ["--notimeout", "--pit"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/apps/${input:utility}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "preLaunchTask": "make utility",
        },
    "inputs": [
        {
          "type": "pickString",
          "id": "utility",
          "description": "Which utility app do you want to run?",
          "options": [
            "utility_1",
            "utility_2",
            "utility_3",
            "utility_4",
          ]
        },
    ]
}
```

The tasks.json configuration file looks like:

```
tasks.json
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "make utility",
            "type": "process",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [ "${input:BuildUtility}" ],
            "group": "build",
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        },
    ],
    "inputs": [
        {
            "type": "pickString",
            "id": "BuildUtility",
            "description": "Which utility do you want to build?",
            "options": [
                "utility_1",
                "utility_2",
                "utility_3",
                "utility_4",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I pass the selection made from launch via preLaunchTask so the task uses that selection, effectively overriding `"${input:BuildUtility}"` so the user wouldn't be promoted to make a selection for the `"args"` field?  Bonus would be having the tasks still ask for a selection if nothing was passed to it?  Thanks.

Comment: It appears this isn't support at the time of this writing.  Made a request to add this feature.  Now just need to wait and see if the community up votes it enough to add it.

Comment: Searched a lot for this and ended up here. The Feature request @lordhog mentions is this I assume: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95158 unfortunately it was closed due to lack of upvotes. So still does not seem to be possible

Answer (score 0):

This is now supported by Visual Studio code via the new `pickString` input type.

[Reference in the documentation:](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables)

> `pickString`: Shows a Quick Pick dropdown to let the user select from several options.

Here is an example on how to create a select input:

```json
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "type": "pickString",
      "id": "myString",
      "description": "Pick an option:",
      "options": [
        "foo",
        "bar",
        "baz"
      ],
      "default": "foo"
    }
  ]
}
```